# how to edit or copy data loaded renames of my own published sheet/project in qliksense

Tags: qliksense

This is the first time we decided to use QlikSense. So I am a newbie.
I have developed a sheet for a table report.
I loaded a lot of data and I made a lot of renames on the fields when they are loaded from the database to look pretier for searching in the Analytics tab.
In order to show my progress to my boss I had to publish my work. He wanted to use another type of user. So I published the App, but I lost the ability to edit anything especially the data loading. Unfortunately that means I have to restart my work.

Any suggestions on how to restore my progress?
(It sounds to be an off-topic question probably...because there is no code in here)

Comment: By publishing your work you mean that you have published the app right?

Comment: yes, I published the app

Comment: It doesn't let me edit anything; especially the data loading even when I copy the project and the sheet

Comment: You cant edit the script once app is published (you can technically but its not recommended). The published objects also cant be changed. You should be able to make copy of the sheet and then make changes visible to yourself. If you want to update the app (script, core objects, new sheets etc) you need to duplicate the published app, make the required changes and re-publish again

Comment: @StefanStoichev if I unpublish the app I still can't edit. After cloning the app I still can not. What am I missing? Is it something in the setup or the installation on our server?

Comment: As far as i know - when duplicate an app (and you are the owner of it) you should be able to edit the objects. By default there are security rule(s) in place which prevent you to see the load script on duplicated apps. But these are the default rules. Your instance might have a custom security rules which are preventing you to edit after duplication

Comment: @StefanStoichev Yes, that was reason for being unable to edit in our case. Would you please provide a link with a step by step solution how to change these default settings? That would be enough for the question to be answered.

Comment: I need to write something somewhere but in general there is a Security Rule named "Stream". Part of the condition is `and resource.objectType != "app_appscript" and resource.objectType != "loadmodel`. This is the part that excludes the `Load Script` part and the `Data Model`. Be careful ... editing this rule will affect all apps/users!